# Access Database - Operation must use an updateable query. (Works fine on local)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I checked other questions when i typed the title in, i can't understand anymore. i need to cool down a bit :)

I started asp.net 1,5 week ago everything was working fine on local and i uploaded my site files to ftp server and i'm getting this error:

> Operation must use an updateable query.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Operation must use an updateable query.
>   Source Error: 
>            //*** Goruntulenme sayısını güncelleme //translation updating view count  ***

```
    // This was the old code after checking other same titled questions i changed to this one and still no luck
    //sorgu.Append(" UPDATE sorular SET [goruntulenme] = [goruntulenme] + 1 ");
    //sorgu.Append(" WHERE soruid = @soruid ");
    //komut = new OleDbCommand(sorgu.ToString(), baglanti);
    //komut.Parameters.Add("@soruid", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sorgusoruid.ToString();
    //komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string SqlString = "UPDATE sorular SET [goruntulenme] = [goruntulenme] + 1 WHERE soruid = ?";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, baglanti))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("soruid", sorgusoruid.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Error points to that cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line. The things i checked:
*Table has a primary key
*Code works on local just like i need it
*This is a forum part of my project the simplest way i have 3 tables "users" "questions" and "answers"
*i can log in and log out on server. it works fine but can't update. i guess i'm suspecting permissions because this logging in code works (if you want i can translate variable parts of code).

```
OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\db.accdb"));
    baglan.Open();
    string k_ad = Kullanici.Text;
    string k_sifre = sifre.Text;
    OleDbCommand kontrol = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Kullanicilar WHERE K_Ad='" + k_ad + "' and K_Sfr='" + k_sifre + "'", baglan);
    OleDbDataReader oku = kontrol.ExecuteReader();

    if (oku.Read())
    {
        Session.Add("Kullanici", k_ad);
        Response.Redirect("Forum.aspx");
        lbl.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lbl.Text = "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış";
        lbl.Visible = true;
    }
    baglan.Close();
    baglan.Dispose();
}
```

I don't know what else i can give here as info. pls let me know if any more info you need about that and how can i find that information :))
Ohh and i'm using ms-access database, using sql database server seems more complicated to me.

Comment: Double check to make sure the account that your app pool is running as has write access to the folder your database file is in.

Comment: You're using query string concatenation which vulnerable to SQL injection - use parameters instead. Note that a query is not updateable if the SET and/or WHERE clause use aggregate functions.

Comment: ohh is it why this one works ,,, because its query havent made from aggregate functions. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
OleDbCommand kontrol = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Usr_name='" + username + "' and Usr_pw='" + password + "'", connect);

Comment: squillman here permissions on database folder am i looking right place
[Permissions at Filezilla](http://prntscr.com/j6xjgf)

Comment: Not the ftp permissions.  What is the server you are uploading to?  Is it Windows / IIS?

Comment: OS:Windows Server 2008   and Web Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: Where can i change [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481138/access-db-operation-must-use-updateable-query?rq=1) settings [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481138/access-db-operation-must-use-updateable-query?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i changed database folder permissions on my hosting service provider's website i logged in a panel with same id pw with the ones i use at filezilla there was settings for folders and they were read only i changed them to full access minus deleting and changing ownership